# If $\bigwedge^n V=0$, what can we say about the dimension of the vector space $V$ over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{k}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

The question is this: if the wedge product $\bigwedge^n V=0$, what can we say about the dimension of the vector space $V$? Because $\bigwedge^n V=0$ for all $n>d$, where $\dim V=d<\infty$; but in the first case I don't know what to say. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Necessarily $\dim V < n$. If $d = \dim V$ you know that $\dim \Lambda^n V = \binom{d}{n}$, which is always positive when defined.

Comment: "but in the first case I don't know what to say" - What first case? What cases are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let be $V$ a vector space over a field of characteristic $0$, and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508142/let-be-v-a-vector-space-over-a-field-of-characteristic-0-and-n-in-mathbbn)

Comment: @ZachTeitler Sorry! I mean, if only we know that $\bigwedge^n V=0$, what can we say about dimension of $V$? Can we conclude that is it finite or inifnite and why?

The first case is: If the dimension of $V$ is finite, then $\bigwedge^n V=0$ for all $n>\dim V$. I wish to know the reciprocal statement. Thanks!

Comment: If the dimension of $V$ is infinite then $\bigwedge^n V \neq 0$ for all (finite) $n$. $V$ has a finite-dimensional subspace with dimension $n$ or greater, so the $n$th wedge of that subspace is nonzero. So I guess you could say: $\bigwedge^n V = 0$ if and only if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim V < n$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @ZachTeitler!! It's the same that @LordSharktheUnknown said me. But I don't understand why if $V$ is infinite (dimensionally talking) then $\bigwedge^n V\neq 0$. Where can I consult it? Thanks again!

Comment: @GregoryHouse The idea is that if $W \subseteq V$ is a subspace, then $\bigwedge^n W$ is a subspace of $\bigwedge^n V$. If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, you can just pick an $n$-dimensional subspace $W$, and now  you have identified a nonzero subspace $\bigwedge^n W$ inside $\bigwedge^n V$. So $\bigwedge^n V \neq 0$. I don't know where I would find that specific precise fact. But in general there are books about multilinear algebra and exterior algebra, which might be helpful perhaps. Good luck!